# max interval of definition of a differential equation's solution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the ODE $y'(x)= -{(1+y(x)^2)^2 \over (2y(x))}$.The solution passes for (1,1).
I have to find the max interval of definition of the solution.

$f(x,y)=-{(1+y(x)^2)^2 \over (2y(x))}$.

$f \in C^\infty (R,R\setminus\{0\})$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$y'=-\frac{(1+y^2)^2}{2y}$$
$$\frac{2y}{(1+y^2)^2}dy=-dx$$
$$\frac{d(1+y^2)}{(1+y^2)^2}=-dx$$
$$\int_1^y\frac{d(1+y^2)}{(1+y^2)^2}=-\int_1^x dx$$

Comment: $y^2={(3-2x) \over (2x-1)}$ so $x \in ({1 \over 2},{3 \over 2}]$